# D3 code migration from v3 to v4: Tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I had perfectly working choropleth in d3 v3. But I have to upgrade to use d3 v4. When I upgraded, lots of function stopped working and throwing error messages. I have fixed all error messages and it is showing charts but somehow I am not able to get back hover (tooltip) functionality back on choropleth and bar chart. It was working absolutely perfect in v3 but not able to get in v4.

Can anyone able to explain me the particular reason?

Below is the code for getting tooltip.

```
// Tooltip
var tt_choropleth = d3.select("#svganchor").append("div")   
            .attr("class", "tooltip_choropleth")                
            .style("opacity", 0);
// Load CSV File function here
{
 d3.selectAll(".bar_ch").on("mousemove", function(d) {
        tt_choropleth.html("<strong>" + d.country_name + "</strong> <br>"+ $("#opt :selected").text() + " count: <strong>" + d[disaster] + "</strong>")
                  .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 12 + 'px')
                  .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 25 + 'px')
                  .style("opacity", 0.9);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        tt_choropleth.style("opacity", 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it related to .html()? I am suspecting that...  Please help

Comment: This code works, you have some other problem (position not absolute, no jQuery etc...). Since you have another problem somewhere, the only way to help you is if you create a working fiddle, plunkr or whatever.

Comment: Yes @GerardoFurtado, it was a different problem. I am able to find out now. In HTML, I used <svg width="1350" height="600" style="padding-left: 50px;" id="svganchor"></svg> instead of <div width="1350" height="600" style="padding-left: 50px;" id="svganchor"></div>.  Earlier it was creating an SVG inside another SVG